# Create a txt file with Sagemaker Lifecycle Configuration script

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I'm unable to get Sagemaker Lifecycle Configuration to create a plain `.txt` file in the directory with my jupyter notebooks when the sagemaker notebook starts.

In the future I'll add text to this file, but creating the file is the first step.

**Start notebook script:**

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

touch filename.txt
```

**Note:** I have edited my notebook to add this lifecycle configuration.

But when the notebook starts and I open it, the file does not exist. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You are creating the file in the root directory.

Use the terminal option of your notebook to explore
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The working directory of the Lifecycle Configuration script is "/" and Jupyter starts up from the "*/home/ec2-user/SageMaker*" directory. So, if you create a file outside "*/home/ec2-user/SageMaker*", it will not be visible inside the Jupyter file browser.

To address this, you can modify your script to

```
touch /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/filename.txt
```

Thanks for using Amazon SageMaker!